# Query not working in wp_get_recent_posts()

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to pass a `$post_query` inside `wp_get_recent_posts()` which has the following arguments:

```php
$post_query = array(
     'numberposts' => 3,
     'include' => ['1', '8', '12', '14'],
)

$recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $post_query );
```

I was expecting it to return only 3 posts. The purpose of doing this is so that I can easily control the number of posts in the page given a list of post IDs. But still it returns the 4 posts inside `include` query.

Is this the right behavior? I can do something like:

```php
$recent_posts = array_slice( $recent_posts, 0, $post_query[ 'numberposts' ] );
```

but I am not sure if this is the right approach for that. Any help would be appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: I think it's because of `include` parameter which is "An array of post IDs to retrieve, sticky posts will be included." So that means you get all the posts mentioned in the parameter.

Comment: This makes sense. Thank you so much!